# How to get a boolean that indicate whether it is swiping in UITABLEVIEWCELL when it is during the swipe action?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe

I'm making a tableView reloaded  very often.
When the tableView reload the cell during the swipe action, the swipe action will interrupt immediately as well as it is during the scrolling and dragging.
I can get these state through `isDragging` and `isDecelerating` except the swiping action.
Is their any "isSwiping" thing can do the same thing?

Comment: so are you looking for the delegate event which can tell you that whether any cell has edit actions (by swiping left) visible or not?
If it is, you may check this tableView(_:editActionsForRowAt:). You can set any boolean value when this method is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastEditedCell:UITableViewCell? // property of the class

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    let editingCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    lastEditedCell = editingCell
    //Your Code

}
```